# Define callbacks to numpy structured array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have an [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.doc.structured_arrays) in numpy which looks like:

```
myType = np.dtype([('label', 'U16'), ('value', np.float32), ('max_value', np.float32)])

arr = np.array([ [ ('a', 1., 10.), ('b', 2., 10.) ]
               , [ ('c', 3., 10.), ('d', 4., 10.) ]], dtype=myType )
```

I can index each attribute of the struct using regular bracket syntax like

```
>>> arr['value'] 
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.]], dtype=float32)
```

Supose I'd like to get the ratio `value / max_value`. This can be easily achive using a regular function

```
>>> percentage = lambda arr: arr['value'] / arr['max_value']
>>> percentage(arr)
array([[0.1, 0.2],
       [0.3, 0.4]], dtype=float32)
```

But this looks a little bit akward from user's point of view since some attributes are define within the array and others as functions. Is there anyway to define the callback as an attribute? Like below:

```
>> arr['percentage'] # Execute the percentage function
array([[0.1, 0.2],
       [0.3, 0.4]], dtype=float32)
```

The reason to use a callback is to keep a consistent state, so if you modify `value`, the `percentage` attribute will keep consistent.

Comment: That would a complex task, involving a custom class with its own `__getitem__`.  What you want is usually called a `property` in Python, and is accessed with the attribute syntax, e.g. `arr.percentage`.  `arr['value']` uses indexing syntax.  For a structured array it looks a lot like `dict` index (with a `key` word) (though an array is not a dictionary).

Comment: I think the best solution is kind of your proposal. Creating a new object which internally handles a structured array and define properties.